# Find the key and return true in a deeply nested set of arrays php

Tags: php, arrays

So there are tons of questions like this, but I haven't found an answer the suits my desired outcome.

consider the following array:

```
array:13 [
  "Peripheral Neuropathy" => array:3 [
    "name" => "peripheral_neuropathy"
    "value" => array:1 [
      0 => "yes"
    ]
    "dependencies" => array:5 [
      "neuropathy_staging_fap" => array:1 [
        0 => "2"
      ]
      "neuropathy_staging_pnd" => array:1 [
        0 => "II"
      ]
      "specify_type" => array:1 [
        0 => "Sensory"
      ]
      "autonomic" => array:1 [
        0 => "yes"
      ]
      "sensory_fiber_size" => array:1 [
        0 => "Small"
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "Neuropathic pain" => array:3 [
    "name" => "neuropathic_pain"
    "value" => array:1 [
      0 => "yes"
    ]
    "dependencies" => []
  ]
  "Functional Motor Assessment" => array:3 [
    "name" => "functional_motor_assessment"
    "value" => array:1 [
      0 => "Yes"
    ]
    "dependencies" => array:3 [
      "functional_motor_assessment_test_name" => "sample"
      "functional_motor_assessment_test_score" => "10"
      "functional_motor_assessment_date" => "2020-02-11"
    ]
  ]
  "Assessment name" => array:3 [
    "name" => "functional_motor_assessment_test_name"
    "value" => "sample"
    "dependencies" => []
  ]
  "Assessment Score" => array:3 [
    "name" => "functional_motor_assessment_test_score"
    "value" => "10"
    "dependencies" => []
  ]
  "Assessment Date" => array:3 [
    "name" => "functional_motor_assessment_date"
    "value" => "2020-02-11"
    "dependencies" => []
  ]
  "Carpal Tunnel Syndrome" => array:3 [
    "name" => "carpal_tunnel_syndrome"
    "value" => array:1 [
      0 => "yes"
    ]
    "dependencies" => []
  ]
  "EMG" => array:3 [
    "name" => "emg"
    "value" => array:1 [
      0 => "yes"
    ]
    "dependencies" => array:5 [
      "emg_type" => array:1 [
        0 => "Median"
      ]
      "median_amplitude" => "10"
      "median_CV" => "10"
      "median_tml" => "10"
      "median_size" => array:1 [
        0 => "7cm"
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "EMG Type" => array:3 [
    "name" => "emg_type"
    "value" => array:1 [
      0 => "Median"
    ]
    "dependencies" => array:4 [
      "median_amplitude" => "10"
      "median_CV" => "10"
      "median_tml" => "10"
      "median_size" => array:1 [
        0 => "7cm"
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "Amplitude" => array:3 [
    "name" => "median_amplitude"
    "value" => "10"
    "dependencies" => []
  ]
  "CV" => array:3 [
    "name" => "median_CV"
    "value" => "10"
    "dependencies" => []
  ]
  "TML" => array:3 [
    "name" => "median_tml"
    "value" => "10"
    "dependencies" => []
  ]
  "Size" => array:3 [
    "name" => "median_size"
    "value" => array:1 [
      0 => "7cm"
    ]
    "dependencies" => []
  ]
]
```

As we can see there are duplicates, for example look at: `Functional Motor Assessment` under `dependencies` - this is correct, but directly under `Functional Motor Assessment` is `Assessment name` with the name `functional_motor_assessment_test_name`.

This is the duplicate. This specific array, `Assessment name` should not exist because the name already exists in `Functional Motor Assessment`'s dependencies array.

So I thought, I will write the following function:

```
protected function alreadyExists(array $values, string $fieldName) {
    if (empty($values)) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            if ($k === 'dependencies' && !empty($value[$k])) {
                return array_key_exists($fieldName, $value[$k]);
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

where `$value` is the above array and in this case `$fieldName` would be (for example) `functional_motor_assessment_test_name`.

The idea here is that this should walk through the array looking for any key that matches: `functional_motor_assessment_test_name` and return true if found or false if not (false if the (above) array is empty).

Theres a couple rules:

- Return false if the value array is empty, because obviously it wont exist.
- Return false if never found
- Skip the check if the the `dependencies` array is empty (it can be empty sometimes).

  - This is where it should move on to the next array, so if not found in `Peripheral Neuropathy` move on to `Neuropathic pain` and so on ...

I think this function has to be recursive, but I am not sure where to put the recursive aspect, to say: well I didn't find it in `Peripheral Neuropathy`, let's check `Neuropathic pain` and so on and so forth. Until it is either found or not.

I tried `array_walk_recursive`, but as I expected while reading the docs, there is no way to break from that kind of function - so I thought, this function I have is on the right track, I just need to make it recursive.

**Ideas?**

Comment: Use a `foreach` loop. Make the recursive call on the current element, and if it succeeds you can return immediately, otherwise you keep looping.

Comment: I don't think you need recursion here, just two passes; one to get all dependencies, and the other to match each name against the dependencies you've just found.

Comment: I assumed dependencies could be nested more deeply.

Comment: But the dependency structure looks nothing like the top level elements, though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to loop over the second level arrays, just get the `dependencies` element directly with indexing.

```
public function alreadyFound(array $values, string $fieldName) {
    foreach ($values as $item) {
        if (!empty($item['dependencies']) && array_key_exists($fieldName, $item['dependencies'])) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If there can be dependencies nested within dependencies, you do need a recursive solution.

```
protected function alreadyExists(array $values, string $fieldName) {
    if (array_key_exists($fieldName, $values)) {
        return true;
    }

    foreach ($values as $item) {
        if (!empty($item['dependencies']) && $this->alreadyExists($item['dependencies'], $fieldName) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```